# Urllib2 url open delay between opening webpage and getting html data

Tags: python, python-2.7, urllib2

I have a small python script that grabs some data from a webpage but the data on the webpage changes after a hit to the webpage. Is it possible to open the url wait a few seconds then return the data? My code is below I tried to add a few sleep commands but I doubt it is as simple as that.... any ideas?

```
url = "http://www.test.com"
        cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
        opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
        req = urllib2.Request(url)
        req.add_header('User-Agent','Mozilla/5.0')
#       time.sleep(5)
        resp = opener.open(req)
#       time.sleep(5)
        htmltext = resp.read()
```

Comment: What do you want to accomplish by waiting?

Comment: So when I first hit the page (using browser or script) I noticed that some of the data changes for a few seconds then remains steady. I want to grab the latest data.

Answer (score 0):

the sleep command should work. IIRC, the read command reads the site in its current state, so if the website changes from the time you open the site to the time you read it, the read() function should grab the most upto-date html code.